# Clean url in php mvc

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory-structure

In first `.htaccess`,I send `url` to `public/index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

And my `public/index.php`:

```
<?php
// define root path of the site
if(!defined('ROOT_PATH')){
define('ROOT_PATH','../');
}

require_once ROOT_PATH.'function/my_autoloader.php';

use application\controllers as controllers;

 $uri=strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $actionName='';
 $uriData=array();
 $uriData=preg_split('/[\/\\\]/',$uri );

 $actionName = (!empty($uriData[3])) ? preg_split('/[?].*/', $uriData[3] ): '' ;
 $actionName =$actionName[0];
 $controllerName = (!empty($uriData[2])) ? $uriData[2] : '' ;

 switch ($controllerName) {
case 'manage':
    $controller = new Controllers\manageController($controllerName,$actionName);
    break;
default:
    die('ERROR WE DON\'T HAVE THIS ACTION!');
    exit;
    break;
  }

// function dispatch send url to controller layer 
$controller->dispatch();
?>
```

I have this directory :

- application

  - controller
  - models
  - view
- public

  - `css`
  - `java script`
  - index.php
- `.htaccess`

I want to have clean `URL` for example `localhost/lib/manage/id/1` instead of `localhost/lib/manage?id=1`,what should I do ?

Comment: In this URL `localhost/lib/manage/id/1` which folder name strings are dynamic and which ones are fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current rewrite rules, everything is already redirected to your `index.php` file. And, as you are already doing, you should parse the URL to find all these URL parameters. This is called routing, and most PHP frameworks do it this way. With some simple parsing, you can transform `localhost/lib/manage/id/1` to an array:

```
array(
    'controller' => 'manage',
    'id' => 1
)
```

We can simply do this, by first splitting the URL on a '/', and then looping over it to find the values:

```
$output = array();
$url = split('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// the first part is the controller
$output['controller'] = array_shift($url);

while (count($url) >= 2) {
    // take the next two elements from the array, and put them in the output
    $key = array_shift($url);
    $value = array_shift($url);
    $output[$key] = $value;
}
```

Now the `$output` array contains a key => value pair like you want to. Though note that the code probably isn't very safe. It is just to show the concept, not really production-ready code.

Comment: when i have 2 id,what do i do? and how can find that which id?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear how to actually parse the URL.

Comment: thanks, but now i have problem about `css` file address and images address, how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by capturing part of the URL and and placing it as a querystring.

```
RewriteRule /lib/manage/id/([0-9]+) /lib/manage?id=$1 [L]
```

The string inside the parenthesis  will be put into the $1 variable. If you have multiple `()` they will be put into $2, $3 and so on.